# Use Holder inequality to show $f_n * g_n$ converges to $f*g$ uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, proof-explanation, lp-spaces, convolution

Assume that $G$ is a locally compact abelian group.
Let $C_c(G)$ be a set of complex-valued continuous functions with compact support.
Let $C_0(G)$ be a set of complex-valued continuous functions which vanish at infinity.

The following is extracted from 'Fourier Analysis on Groups' by Rudin, page $5:$

> Proposition: If $1 < p < \infty, 1/p + 1/q = 1, f \in L^p(G)$ and $g \in L^q(G),$ then $f*g \in C_0(G).$

Proof: Choose sequences $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ in $C_c(G)$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_p \rightarrow 0$ and $\|g_n - g\|_q \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$ **Holder's inequality shows that $f_n * g_n \rightarrow f*g$ uniformly.** If $f , g \in C_c(G),$ then $f*g \in C_c(G).$ It follows that **$f_n * g_n \in C_c(G).$**. **Hence, $f*g \in C_0(G).$**

> Question: $(1)$ How to use Holder inequality to show that $f_n *g_n$ converges to $f*g$ uniformly. 
>   $(2):$ How to obtain $f*g \in C_0(G)$?

For question $(1),$ we need to show that for any $\varepsilon>0,$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ and all $x \in G,$ we have 
$$|(f_n *g_n)(x) - (f*g)(x)| < \varepsilon.$$

My attempt: 
By definition of convolution, we have 
$$|(f_n *g_n)(x) - (f*g)(x)|  = \left| \int_G f_n(x-y)g_n(y) dy   - \int_G f(x-y) g(y)dy\right| .$$
I do not see how to apply Holder inequality here.

I have no idea how to start question $(2).$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. We have that
$$|(f_n*g_n)(x) - (f*g)(x)| \leq  \int_G |f_n(x-y)-f(x-y)||g_n(y) |dy\\ +    \int_G |f(x-y)| |g_n(y) -g(y)|dy $$
Then use [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality),
\begin{align*}
|(f_n*g_n)(x) - (f*g)(x)|&\leq  \left(\int_G |f_n(x-y)-f(x-y)|^pdy\right)^{1/p} \|g_n\|_q\\&\quad+ \left(\int_G |f(x-y)|^pdy\right)^{1/p}
\|g_n-g\|_q\\
&= \|f_n -f \|_p\|g_n\|_q+\|f\|_p\|g_n-g\|_q.
\end{align*}

Comment: No, you are right, it is not crucial here.

Comment: But $\|g_n\|_q$ depends on $n,$ right? How to make the term $\|f_n - f\|_p \|g_n\|_q$ small?

Comment: @Idonknow $\|g_n\|_q\to \|g\|_q$ therefore $\|g_n\|_q$ is bounded

Comment: Oops, I forgot the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: How about my question $(2)?$

Comment: Note that $\mbox{supp}(f∗g)\subset\mbox{supp}(f)+\mbox{supp}(g)$.

Comment: How does the inclusion help explaining $f*g \in C_0(G)$?

Comment: If each $h_n$ has compact support and $h_n$ converges uniformly to $h$ then $h$ vanish at infinity. Proof. Let $x_n\to +\infty$ then there is $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $\|h_n-h\||<\epsilon$. Let $m\geq N$ such that $h_m(x_n)=0$ for all $n\geq N'\geq N$. Then $|h(x_n)|\leq |h_m(x_n)|+\|h_n-h\||\leq \epsilon$ which means that $|h(x_n)|\to 0$.

Comment: What is $N^{\prime}$?

Comment: How do we know that $m$ exists such that $h_m(x_n) = 0?$ Why can't it be that $h_m(x_n) \neq 0$ for all natural number $m?$ Maybe the point $x_n$ lies in support of all $h_m$?